# How to have dynamic segments and pass objects and query params all at the same time to a route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router, ember-query-params

I am trying to transit to a route called home with the following url:

```
"home/dynamictext1/dynamictext2?queryparam1=2&queryparams2=3"
```

i also need to pass an object called currentData to the route as well. here is my current code. I was wondering where i should add currentData object and how to access it. if this is not possible is there a better way to pass an object to my new route?

```
this.transitionToRoute('home',dynamictext1, dynamictext2,{ queryParams:params});

this.route('home', { path: '/:dynamictext1/:dynamictext2' });
```

Comment: why do you need to pass currentData around? what is it? can you put it in a service instead? if you can, then you can simply retrieve it by injecting the service into your route and getting currentData from within the model hook

Comment: i get currentData whenever i click on a specific hyperlink and i need that to be passed to my new route for some calculations. Thank you using services is a good idea